# Error trying to start Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this issue rying to start server on Ruby on Rails.

```
C:\Users\ogautier\RoR\holamundo>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `<module:Helper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.8/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ogautier/RoR/holamundo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using Ruby version 2.2 on windows and Nokogiri does not provide support for that combination as of yet.

I guess you have to wait for it's next release.

[For more info](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256)